# How can I configure GitHub so that all issues are automatically assigned?

Tags: github

If it is possible, how can I configure a public GitHub repo so that all issues are automatically assigned?

The closest I can get, via https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation, is:

> "You can mass-edit from this page: close, reopen, add labels, assign to users or add to milestones."

As the gitHub web UI doesn't allow me to sort issues by assignee, it's a little-more-difficult than I could wish for to keep things in order.

Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to automate the process is through  a script:

- listing the issues
- assigning someone to the one without any assignee

That should be possible with the [GitHub API V3](http://developer.github.com/v3/), and its [Issue API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue)

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number
```

(you can use `POST` instead of `PATCH`)

[This script](https://gist.github.com/ernestom/1512186) import and assign cases:

```go
// GitHub API endpoint for /repos/:user/:repo/issues
const GH_API = "https://USER:PASS@api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/issues"

// GitHub logins to assign tickets to. The first one is considered the default.
var validAssignees = []string{"LOGIN1", "LOGIN2"}

...

// Posts the new JSON-encoded issue to GitHub using the given ticket.
func postIssue(ticket Ticket, repo string) {
  bodyType := "application/json"
  jsonIssue := strings.NewReader(encodeTicket(ticket))
  url := fmt.Sprintf(GH_API, repo)

  resp, respErr := http.Post(url, bodyType, jsonIssue)
  checkError(respErr)

  fmt.Println(resp.Status)
  http.DumpResponse(resp, true)
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of needing to use the APIs, but as you've suggested it, it seems to be a great idea.